# How can I prevent FluentMigrator adding a NULL or NOT NULL to the end of a column definition when creating a table in SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql-server, fluent

I have created a test table with this code

```
Create.Table("ComputedColumnTest")
        .WithColumn("Id").AsGuid().PrimaryKey().WithDefaultValue("(newid())").Indexed().NotNullable()
        .WithColumn("Num").AsInt32()
        .WithColumn("NumSquared").AsComputedColumn("(([Num]) * ([Num]))");
```

I have added `AsComputedColumn` as an extension method:

```
public static class ICreateTableColumnAsTypeSyntaxExtensions
{
    public static ICreateTableColumnOptionOrWithColumnSyntax AsComputedColumn(this ICreateTableColumnAsTypeSyntax createTableColumnAsTypeSyntax, string computation)
    {
        return createTableColumnAsTypeSyntax.AsCustom(" as " + computation);
    }
}
```

When I try and run the migration, I get the following message.

> An error occured executing the following SQL:
> CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ComputedColumnTest] ([Id] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_ComputedColumnTest_Id] DEFAULT N'(newid())', [Num] INT NOT NULL, [NumSquared]  as (([Num]) * ([Num])) NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT [PK_ComputedColumnTest] PRIMARY KEY ([Id]))
>
> Only UNIQUE or PRIMARY KEY constraints can be created on computed columns, while CHECK, FOREIGN KEY, and NOT NULL constraints require that computed columns be persisted.

If I edit the create statement, to remove the not null from the computed column definition, it works

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ComputedColumnTest] 
(
    [Id] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL 
         CONSTRAINT [DF_ComputedColumnTest_Id] DEFAULT N'(newid())',
    [Num] INT NOT NULL,
    [NumSquared] AS (([Num]) * ([Num])),  -- NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_ComputedColumnTest] PRIMARY KEY ([Id])
)
```

If I add `.Nullable()` to the column definition, the `NOT NULL` gets replaced with `NULL` and fails in the same way.

Comment: More a workaround than a solution but if you add `PERSISTED` at the end then the `NOT NULL` is allowed, as the error indicates.

Comment: Thanks, but in this case, I don't want to persist the column.

But I have subsequently come up with a (truly horrible workaround) which is to create the table without the computed column,
then add the computed column with

Create.Column("NumSquared").OnTable("ComputedColumnTest").AsCustom(" as (([Num]) * ([Num])) --");

which comments out anything following the computed column definition. This approach doesn't work on the table creation, as all the table creation code is generated as a single line.

Comment: There comes a point where you have to recognize that automated tooling won't do what you want it to do and you need to manage the schema separately. I'd expect that you're at that point.

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into the same issue myself. Weird that both `NULL` and `NOT NULL` both throw the same error but completely omitting doesn't. There doesn't seem to be a way to tell FluentMigrator to omit whether it's `NULL` or `NOT NULL`.

I ended up changing my migration to use `Execute.Sql` and just used raw sql instead of using the `Create` way. So your migration would end up looking like this:

```
Execute.Sql(@"
  CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ComputedColumnTest] 
  (
    [Id] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL 
         CONSTRAINT [DF_ComputedColumnTest_Id] DEFAULT N'(newid())',
    [Num] INT NOT NULL,
    [NumSquared] AS (([Num]) * ([Num])),  -- NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_ComputedColumnTest] PRIMARY KEY ([Id])
  )
");
```